# Camel Test - how to skip Endpoint used in ConsumerTemplate within a processor

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I implemented a service that uses a polling consumer. The pattern is very similar to the one [here](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) (see "Timer Based Polling Consumer").

This is my variant:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("quartz2://" + SCHEDULE + "?cron=" + checkNotNull(cron)).routeId(IN_ROUTE)
            .process(fetchMessages)
    ;
}
```

FetchMessages Processor:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        exchange = consumerTemplate.receive(MainRoute.ACTIVE_MQ + ":queue:" + "source", TIMEOUT);
        //no more messages within timeout
        if (exchange == null){
            break;
        }
        producerTemplate.send(MidRoute.MID_PLUG, exchange);
    }
}
```

My Problem is: How to skip the activemq endpoint within test?

So far i tried to skip it by means of camels test support:

```
@Override
public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
    return "(" + MainRoute.ACTIVE_MQ + ".*)|" + MidRoute.MID_PLUG;
}
```

and with intercept:

```
@Before
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    context.getRouteDefinition(InRoute.IN_ROUTE).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            replaceFromWith(in);
            interceptSendToEndpoint(MainRoute.ACTIVE_MQ + ":queue:" + "source")
                .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                .to(amqMockSource);
        }
    });
}
```

Both with no avail. ActiveMq endpoint is still called resulting in connection refused exception.

So how to skip endpoints used within beans?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the weave mechanism in Camel.

1. Start by giving your route an id using `.routeId(")` and then same goes for your .process("") an id. So write `.process("fetchMessages").id("myId")`
2. We then need to use the weave component to remove the processor.

Something like this in your test.

```
   @Override
   public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

 @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    context.getRouteDefinition("YourRouteId").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder()  {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        weaveById("myId").replace().setBody().constant("Some response"));
      }
    });    
}
```

Basically we are saying that we want to use AdviceWith and then we look in the route with a given routeId for a given method with a given id and replace it with some response body. This is the response you expect to receive from your activemq.

Comment: thanks, i hoped there is a way to test the route with the processor. without the processor the route is doing nearly nothing.

Comment: Well in your processor you are mostly receiving from some activemq queue?

Comment: Alternatively you could create a route in your unit test and allow that to put a message on a local activemq instance if you want to do integration tests.

Comment: thanks - the integration test was the first i did and it is running fine.